# Im trying to remove glare from an image using opencv and i have the mask too

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

This is the error
it says (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats) The mask must be 8-bit 1-channel image in function 'icvInpaint'

```
import numpy as np
#from scipy.misc import bytescale
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread("C:/Users/lbollam/Documents/forpy/Image_with_glare.jpeg")
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
mask = cv2.imread("C:/Users/lbollam/Documents/forpy/Mask.jpeg")
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
#mask1=bytescale(mask1)

f = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
f.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(image)
f.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(mask)
plt.show(block=True)
Image_withoutglare = cv2.inpaint(image,mask, 21, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
f = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
f.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(Image_withoutglare)
```

Comment: As the error message indicates, your `mask` must be single channel, but actually is three channel, cf. `mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`. You haven't included your images (please do that by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66391633/edit) your question), but I guess, it's some grayscale or even binary image? Then try something like `mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`, such that `mask` becomes single channel.

Comment: Hey thanks, it worked